# Html.fromHtml() fail to parse string that starts with <

Tags: android, html-parsing

I am using `Html.fromHtml()` in my android app to render text. But when I pass  as string too display, `Html.fromHtml()` returns empty string.

I can think of hacks like appending space sort of things to handle the case, But I want to know the standard way to handle the strings like `<hello>` with `Html.fromHtml(`).

I tried reading the android documentation but dint come across any helpful clues.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the string like this.

```
&lt;hello&gt;
```

Comment: I tried that to, Still the parser getting chocked. The parser is interpreting the opening brace '<' as start of some custom tag  and hello as the tag name.